# using an input box to set up how many times a loop will run

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that puts spaces in a column of numbers, so that each group of 6 numbers have 2 spaces between them, starting from the top of the sheet. After the groups of 6 there can be groups of 5, these need to have 3 spaces between them.
The groups of 6 always appear above the groups of 5.
I would like to have a code that asks how many groups of 6, then asks for how many groups of 5, then puts in the relevant spacing.

```
Sub MacroMan()
Dim x As Integer

x = 8


For i = 1 To CInt(InputBox("Run this many times:"))
'Range("H2").Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("H&x:H&x+1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

'Range("H2:H110").Copy

x = x + 8
Next
End Sub
I've got the code to run now, but I get the following error.
Run-time error '1004'
Method 'Range of object'_'Global'failed
```

Comment: How would the macro know which are groups of 5, and which are groups of 6, etc? Also I suggest removing all these selections, which are not necessary and probably have been put there by the macro recorder. Write this instead:  Range("H72:H73").Insert Shift:=xlDown and remove the SmallScroll lines.

Comment: Thanks David GM, I know how many groups of 6, and how many groups of 5 there are. I would like to use the input box to feed these numbers into the macro.

Comment: Ok, well if it's just that, let me try something just for the loop.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the user for their input and store the answer in a string. Then convert the string to an integer and use it to determine the number of loops.

```
sub AskUser
    dim Answer as string
    dim i as integer
    dim Number as integer

    Answer = Inputbox("Your text here")
    Number = CInt(Answer) 'Note this will throw an error if you enter something that's not a numbeer
    for i = 1 to Number
    'code
    next i
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the same thing, for the amount of times that you specify.

---

**Important:** Always run untested code on a ***copy*** of your data as executed code cannot be undone!

---

```
Sub SO()

Dim x As Integer, i As Integer

x = 8

Application.CutCopyMode = False

For i = 1 To CInt(InputBox("Run this many times:"))
    Range("H" & x & ":H" & x + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    x = x + 8
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm stuck on the following line. Range("H" & x):("H" & x+1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, basically its H8:H9 first time through the loop, then H16:H17 the second time and so on. Can't get the right syntax, have tried Googling to no avail. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try `Range("H" & x & ":H" & x + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown` although the code I've posted doesn't loop through it inserts all the cells in 1 go so I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: I see you've edited your question - I'll edit my response accordingly in a min